# Index of differential function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is it valid to say:

$$\frac{d}{dy} \left( \frac{du(y)}{dy} \right)^n  = \left(\frac{du(y)}{dy}\right)^{n+1}$$

If so, why?

Answer (score 4):

no!
$$
\frac{d}{dy} \left( \frac{du(y)}{dy} \right)^n = n \left( \frac{du(y)}{dy} \right)^{n-1} \frac{d^2u(y)}{dy^2}
$$
what ***is*** true, and which you may have been thinking of, is that:
$$
\frac{d}{dy} \left( \frac{d^nu(y)}{dy} \right)= \frac{d^{n+1}u(y)}{dy}
$$